# Oracle PL/SQL Scalar Variable Size Syntax Ambiguity

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-function, scalar, plsql-package

What types of expressions are allowed for declaring a scalar variable's size in a PL/SQL package?

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=40b1b196b7e2665d2d51c215cf7e35c6) showing size expressions other than numeric literals where some produce errors and others don't.  Below is a snippet.

```sql
create or replace package p as
  vc varchar2(length('four'));
end;
/
Package created.
```

but

```sql
create or replace package p as
  vc varchar2(greatest(3,4)); --PLS-00491: numeric literal required
end;
/
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
```

The previous example with `length()` shows that expressions other than numeric literal are allowed.

Both `length()` and `greatest()` are SQL functions.  Why does one function invoke `PLS-00491` and the other does not?

Note: The syntax for specifying the size of PL/SQL `datatype` does not seem to be provided in the documentation [Scalar Variable Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/scalar-variable-declaration.html#GUID-03124315-0E1E-4154-8EBE-12034CA6AD55).

Using Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd probably have to ask Oracle; but as a guess, `length()` is deterministic, and `greatest()` isn't? (Obviously the result of `greatest(3,4)` isn't going to change; but that function applies to strings too, and then NLS settings would affect the outcome, so overall it can't be deterministic.)

Comment: Genius observation, I never thougt that something like this would ever be possible `varchar2(8000/(1+1))`. BTW your second example sounds like  [conditional compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-DC23291F-006D-49C4-87DA-6B31F19F162A)
`$IF 3 > 4 $THEN
 v_vc varchar2(3) := '3';
$ELSE 
 v_vc varchar2(4) := '4';
$END`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's because the `length()` function is deterministic - the length in characters of the string literal 'four' is always 4 - while `greatest()` is not. As shown [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GREATEST.html), it is affected by NLS settings; so while with my default English/binary settings I see this:

```
select greatest('á', 'b') from dual;

GREATEST('Á','B')
-----------------
á
```

if I change the settings I get a different result:

```
alter session set nls_comp = 'linguistic';
alter session set nls_language = 'spanish';

select greatest('á', 'b') from dual;

GREATEST('Á','B')
-----------------
b
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3067d12d955b33d3fd0a69c55b13bcc1)

While comparing numbers as you are isn't affected by NLS settings, it's the same function, so it's still not deterministic.

So, in theory at least, the size of your PL/SQL variable declared based on `greatest()` could be different depending on your session settings, which isn't tenable.